# Online chess leavers

Tags: learning

I have encountered a profound number of players that simply leave the game when they realize they are losing/in difficult situation, without pressing "I resign" button. This often leaves me waiting a long time for no reason and, consequently, wasting my time.

Is there a site that prohibits this?

Answer (score 4):

Use lichess.org. When your opponent leaves game you can press button 'Claim draw/loss' there

Comment: why should I claim draw/loss when am in winning board?

Comment: I've seen it say claim draw/win, as well.  Usually I play blitz, so I just let it run - but on classical games, I give the opponent "enough time" to get back in... and if they don't, claim whichever makes more sense given the position.

Comment: The exact buttons are 'Claim victory' (to get the win) and 'Call draw' (to make the game a draw).

Answer (score 4):

**Chess.com** has an algorithm which senses whether a user/player is active or not during the game.

I am not very sure but they have a time frame of 5 minutes, during which if they find the player is not active then the game gets abandoned and the opponent wins.

Answer (score 0):

chess.com seems to be the better option. If the opponent leaves the game or gets inactive they have a time period to get back in the game based on what game you're playing(blitz, bullet or standard).

Comment: Same for chess24